# Using SBT and Maven in single project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, akka

- I am migrating my java application which is a single maven module (contains `pom.xml`) to akka.
- I am new to akka(and typesafe ecosystem), but this is what I plan of doing

> ```
> ApplicationActor
>        | 
>  ExistingProjectActor
> ```

where

- ApplicationActor is based on sbt (and is `Supervisor`)
- ExistingProjectActor is current project with pom.xml (and is `Child Actor`)

**Questions**

- Is it possible to use sbt as main build tool but for legacy purpose also include ExistingProjectActor (with `pom.xml`)?

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve from maven within SBT by adding

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

You can also publish back to your maven repository by running `sbt publishM2`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.